# Can plants grow healthily being watered in either deionized or distilled water?

Tags: botany, growth, bioinorganic-chemistry

I want to use deionized/distilled water to water plants from some. I have the choice whether to use tap water, deionized water or distilled water that come from a closed system that has a water cycle, with a preference of "the purer the water the better" for use in the system.

Can someone please provide me references to whether plants in general (most species) need the missing mineral and salt ions for healthy growth? And references to whether they need what's missing in distilled water for healthy growth (no mineral and salt ions and non-volatile organic compounds, to my understanding)? *By references I mean scientific studies - papers or meta-analyses that were done on the topic*

*I can't provide more specifications on the plant species I'm asking about since I have no particular one I already selected to grow but I'm ***considering*** using* Picea abies *(Norway spruce) if I can get it to grow to a Bonsai form.*

Comment: The question as-is shows no research - which we are expected to do here. (There's also the factor of pH, Picea Abies will prefer something more acidic than the  pH7 of distilled water being ericaceous). Can you edit in what you've looked at so far, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I recommend you to start your googling journey by learning about plant macronutrients and micronutrients and compare plant needs with declared content in tap water from your area. Most likely you will find, that salts in drinking water are optimized for humans consumption and not really beneficial for plants. Consider including rain water + fertiliser in your list of options.